# XAMPP Apache wont start

Tags: windows, apache, service, server

Error logs

```
[Wed Oct 07 10:45:33.781957 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5248:tid 380] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 07 10:45:34.086160 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5248:tid 380] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 07 10:45:34.450418 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5248:tid 380] AH00455: Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.5.28 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 07 10:45:34.450418 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5248:tid 380] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul 12 2015 10:56:48
[Wed Oct 07 10:45:34.450418 2015] [core:notice] [pid 5248:tid 380] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Xampp/apache'
[Wed Oct 07 10:45:34.461426 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5248:tid 380] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3408
[Wed Oct 07 10:45:35.852815 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3408:tid 392] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 07 10:45:36.162072 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3408:tid 392] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 07 10:45:36.239123 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3408:tid 392] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: These error logs complain about a misconfigured https listener (mismatch between the installed certificate and the server name), but doesn't mention other issues. Are you sure Apache isn't running (check via taskmanager and netstat)?

Comment: fixed now it I changed ports 80 to 8080  in  httpd.conf and  443 to 4433 in the httpd-ssl.conf

Comment: Thanks for quick reply